# Countdown from current timestamp

Tags: jquery, timestamp, countdown, unix-timestamp

Here is the plugin I'm using:
https://github.com/PragmaticMates/jquery-final-countdown

I can't seem to get this to work when counting down from the current time.  I've tried various things and put what I have right now in a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/michelenarup/f3XX8/4/

```
   $(document).ready(function() {



    $('.countdown').final_countdown({
            'start': 1405707997,
            'end': 1405814400,
            'now': new Date().getTime()
            //'now': 1405707997
    }, function() {
            // Finish Callback
    });
   });
```

I tried using other methods to call in the current unix timestamp:
http://jsfiddle.net/michelenarup/6Dw7Q/10/

```
   var time = Date.now || function() {
       return +new Date;
   };

   $('#timestamp').html( time() );
```

But when I try to include that or anything besides an already generated unix timestamp within the Final-Countdown it breaks the script. This countdown needs to be counting down from NOW to the date. How can I make this happen within this plugin?

Comment: JS `.getTime()` returns a Javascript Timestamp, which is in milliseconds. That means your `now` value is 1000 times bigger than your start/end values, e.g. **WAY** out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this plugin, you need to set the `start` time as well as the `now` time to the current time. And then set the `end` time to a time in the future.

So, in this example, the countdown will be from current time to an hour from now:

```
// This is just used to add hours to the current time in the example below
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

        var currentTime = new Date();
        var futureTime = (new Date()).addHours(1);

        $('.countdown').final_countdown({
                'start': currentTime.getTime(),
                'end': futureTime.getTime(),
                'now': currentTime.getTime()
        }, function() {
                // Finish Callback
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use this to figure out a solution. The final code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/michelenarup/f3XX8/6/